# Simplify unique String check in a Set

Tags: java, set, unique, contains

I wanna generate unique String Ids until it is unique.

My approach is:

```
private Set<String> uniqueIdSet = new HashSet<>();
...

 boolean contains = uniqueIdSet.contains(getRandomId());
    while (contains){
      var randomId = getRandomId();
      contains = uniqueIdSet.contains(randomId);
      if (!contains){
        uniqueIdSet.add(randomId);
      }
    }
```

My question: is there a better way to implement this?

Comment: this might be more suitable for Code Review...

Comment: The main purpose of `Set` is to guarantee that there are no duplicate elements. `add`ing an element already checks for that.

Comment: @f1sh so how would you implement it using default Set logic? try catch?

Comment: @DerBenniAusA `String randomId; do { randomId = getRandomId(); } while (! uniqueIdSet.add(randomId));` --- The `add()` method returns `false` if the value is already in the set, i.e. the value couldn't be added (again), so keep generating a value until it returns `true`, i.e. while it returns `false`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main purpose of Set is to guarantee that there are no duplicate elements. `add`ing an element already checks for that.

Use [the return value](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#add(E)) of `add` to see if the id was already in the `Set`:

```
String randomId = getRandomId();
while (!uniqueIdSet.add(randomId)) {
  randomId = getRandomId();
}
```

EDIT: Take a look at Andreas's comment above, which is even better.